# Is there a better way to assign msgid in django translations?

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, django-i18n, po

I am currently relying on django translations and I am curious to know if there is a better way to pick msgid for translations rather than the usual approach.

For instance:

In order to mark something for translation you have to do the following.

```
variable_name = _("Some Name")
```

and Django picks the msgid in the following way

```
msgid "Some Name"
msgstr "Some Name"
```

I currently would like to see if there is a way in which I can either pass a key to `gettext`

```
_("my string", "my_key")
```

or

An implementation in which the variable name becomes the msgid automatically when django picks up the variable.

```
msgid "variable_name"
msgstr "Some Name"
```

Any idea or suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `msgid` can't be overwritten, it's a source string for translation. But you can use the [`django.utils.translation.pgettext()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.pgettext) function to provide a contextual information:

```py
from django.utils.translation import pgettext

# Use pgettext to specify a custom ID and the original string
print(pgettext("variable_name", "Some Name"))
```

This will appear in the `.po` file as:

```
msgctxt "variable_name"
msgid "Some Name"
msgstr ""
```

In case your string needs pluralization, there is a [`django.utils.translation.npgettext()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.npgettext) function:

```py
from django.utils.translation import npgettext

def show_items(count):
    message = npgettext(
        'variable_name',
        'You have one apple',
        'You have {count} apples',
        count
    )
    print(message.format(count=count))

show_items(1) # Output: You have one apple
show_items(3) # Output: You have 3 apples
```

This will appear in the `.po` file as:

```
msgctxt "variable_name"
msgid "You have one apple"
msgid_plural "You have {count} apples"
```